# Compose error show in upgrade command

Tags: magento2, composer, magento2.4

I have updated Magento version Magento 2.3.5-p1 to Magento 2.4.0 When I am running Magento setup upgrade command

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

then it's showing me below error

```
Module 'Magento_ComposerRootUpdatePlugin':
Running data recurring...Reading /var/www/html/composer.json
Loading config file /var/www/html/var/composer_home/auth.json
Loading config file /var/www/html/composer.json
Loading config file /var/www/html/auth.json
Reading /var/www/html/auth.json
Failed to initialize global composer: Composer could not find the config file: /var/www/html/var/composer_home/composer.json
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting Started" section
Reading /var/www/html/vendor/composer/installed.json
Reading /var/www/html/composer.lock
Checking for "magento/composer-root-update-plugin: 1.0.0" for the Web Setup Wizard...
Reading /var/www/html/var/vendor/magento/composer-root-update-plugin/composer.json
Loading config file /var/www/html/var/composer_home/auth.json
Loading config file /var/www/html/var/vendor/magento/composer-root-update-plugin/composer.json
No Web Setup Wizard update needed for magento/composer-root-update-plugin; version 1.0.0 is 

already in /var/www/html/var.

Module 'Magento_User':
```

I have update composer version by below command

```
composer selfupdate
```

how can I solve this error?

Comment: Have you get solution for the issue. I have faced same issue while setup:upgrade in `magento 2.4.0`

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this issue by removing the below module from composer file and it's updating my composer version 1.10.10

```
"magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.0",
```