# Upgrade Magento 2.3.5 to 2.4.3 version then run setup upgrade command

Tags: magento2.4, magento2.4.3

Run php bin/magento s:up command.

[image: Upgrade]

Comment: Have you tried this solution https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/319444/73212

Comment: Thanks, @MohitRane. It's working fine.

Comment: You can accept the answer to make it helpful for others ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Remove `magento/composer-root-update-plugin` from composer file.

```
"magento/composer-root-update-plugin": "~1.0",
```

**Hope it helps.**